# Showing all models in Django admin panel in development

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I am developing I constantly need to access data from the admin panel but I do not wish to add all models in admin.py since I do not want them to be accessed in production.

Is there a way to show all models in the admin panel in the development environment and hide (part of) them in production automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that would be as simple as this:

```
# my_app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

from .models import MyModel, AnotherModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class AnotherModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

# conditional registration of models
if settings.DEBUG:
    admin.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
    admin.register(AnotherModel, AnotherModelAdmin)
```